# iOS keyboard shortcut for double space to replace with ".", overwrites my UITextfiled data

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a table row which has some data entry by using UITextField.
Lets say I have some data in it "my data"
Next time when I come back to this activity, I want to edit it and append with . using double space keyboard shortcut to get the result as "my data."

The issue is when I use double space shortvut it overwrite it and replace the value of UITextfield with ". "

Is there any way to append this shortcut.

I hope I explain my problem correctly.

Comment: I had this same problem -- it was really weird. I believe it only happened on iOS 6. It only happened when I presented a modal view controller (a `UIImagePickerController` to be precise) before I had resigned the text field's first responder status, and then tried the period shortcut. Do you have a more general problem where it always happens?

Comment: Yes its happening on all my view where I have provided editing of values on table row with the help of UITextField. You may be right on iOS 6 version. I did not test this problem on lower version though.

Answer (score 0):

Well after lot of digging and some manipulation I have following answer, this could help if some one has the same issue.

use following delegate call

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

and copy the following code to fix the issue described above.

```
//Check for double space, hot key shortcut provided on keyboard.
if((range.location > 0 &&
    [string length] > 0 &&
    [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:0]] &&
    [[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[[textField text] characterAtIndex:range.location - 1]])) {

    //Manually replace the space with your own space, programmatically
    NSRange backward = NSMakeRange(range.location - 1, 1);
    textField.text = [rightTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:backward withString:@". "];
    return NO;
}
```

This will append . to the existing data in UITextField.

Still looking for better answer.